# A nonnegative function having area proportional to arc length (Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$, ex. $14.13.16$)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is to find the non-negative function which whose ordinate set over an arbitrary interval has an area proportional to the arc length of the graph above the interval.

The area is $\int_0^x f(t) dt$, the arc length is $\int_0^x \sqrt{1 + f'(t)}dt$. If we assume that $f(x)$ is continuous, we get $\tag{1} kf(x) = \sqrt{1 + f'(x)} \implies k^2y^2 = 1 + y'$. This is a Riccati equation, and it has a solution $\frac{1}{k}$. Another solution is of form $\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{v}$, where $v$ satisfies $\tag{2} v' +2kv = k^2$.

When I solve that equation, I get $v=v(0)e^{-2kx} + \frac{k}{2}e^{-2kx} - \frac{k}{2}$, which means that the solution of the original equation $1$ is $\frac{1}{k} + \frac{2e^{2kx}}{c+k-ke^{2kx}}$, but that doesn't seem to be the solution of the equation $1$.

Can you find where I made a mistake?

Comment: Squaring produces additional solutions.

Comment: @geetha290krm It should still satisfy the squared equality on the RHS of implication in $1$, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Are you saying that even if it was correctly satisfying the right side of the implication, it would not satisfy the left side of the implication?

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks! Can you please write those 2 comments as full answer, so I can close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any mistake you made in solving Eq. $(1)$ is irrelevant, as the latter is incorrect. The arc length is given by $\int_0^{x}\sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2}\,dt$, not by
$\int_0^{x}\sqrt{1+f'(t)}\,dt$, so the correct differential equation to be solved is $kf(x)=\sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2}$, or $$k^2y^2=1+(y')^2.$$